# What in Lubuntu would cause monitor to alternate Analog/Digital and stay in black screen?

Tags: lubuntu, display, startup, monitor

### 18 September 2018 original post

I just installed latest stable version of Lubuntu from USB. Tested it first running off the USB and the interface worked but after I installed and restarted as it requested, it defaults to starting Lubuntu and I see the loading screen but then the entire screen goes black except for the upper left corner (I think display built into monitor itself) alternating Analog / Digital rapidly. I cant do anything via the keyboard so eventually I just shut it down manually.

I tried logging into Lubuntus equivalent of Safe Mode but it just spontaeously shut off. I'm not sure if it's due to overheating? I figured since Lubuntu used minimal RAM this wouldn't be a risk merely for starting it up. Vista's safe mode didn't seem to cause that and I know it was more resource intensive.

---

### 20 March 2019 reply to DK bose

per your instructions

```
jay@KingdomClubs:~$ inxi -Fxxxz
System:    Host: KingdomClubs Kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic i686
           bits: 32 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) info: lxpanel dm: lightdm
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: HP-Pavilion product: GC674AA-ABA m8120n serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTek model: Basswood3G v: 1.05 serial: N/A
           BIOS: Phoenix v: 5.07 date: 05/24/2007
           Chassis: Hewlett-Packard type: 3 v: 1111 serial: N/A
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core2 Quad (-MCP-) 
           arch: Conroe rev.7 cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 19199
           clock speeds: min/max: 1600/2400 MHz 1: 1599 MHz 2: 1601 MHz
           3: 1599 MHz 4: 1599 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G72 [GeForce 7350 LE]
           bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:01d0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: vesa,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@0.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:284b
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-43-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: ff00
           bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:104b
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Gemtek WUBR-177G [Ralink RT2571W]
           driver: rt73usb v: 2.3.0 usb-ID: 002-002 chip-ID: 15a9:0004
           IF: wlx00c0a8eacdd5 state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 640.1GB (51.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: Hitachi_HDT72503 size: 320.1GB
           serial: <filter>
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Hitachi_HDT72503 size: 320.1GB
           serial: <filter>
Partition: ID-1: / size: 292G used: 11G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 1.03GB used: 0.00GB (0%)
           fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-1
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 70.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 189 Uptime: 9 min Memory: 578.3/3024.7MB
           Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191 running in x-terminal-emul) inxi: 2.3.56 
jay@KingdomClubs:~$
```

Does this help? I'm not sure if it helps ID the problem

Comment: At some point, you could share details of the machine you're using. If you can install software, install `inxi` and post the output of `inxi -Fxxxz` here.

Comment: DK Bose I installed inxi and added the output above.